# fail in reading from edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I wrote a code in java that should get a number from an `EditText` by clicking on a button and print it in console.that's so simple but when I click on the edittext in order to write a number in it I see this message in `logcat` that 
:

```
09-16 23:57:02.121: W/Editor(27812): GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior
```

and after clicking on the button nothing happens!

this is a part of my code :

```
  EditText txt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

             Editable t1;
             t1=txt1.getText();


       if(!(t1.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0") || t1.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))){

       int n1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.toString());
       int m1 = n1/100000;
       System.out.print(n1);
        System.out.print(m1);
       }
```

I'll be happy if anyone can help me by that :)

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `Strings` you should use the `equals()` on the `String` `Class`.

Comment: since that I get the message when I click on the "EditText" , I think the problem is not related to the java code...isn't it ?

Comment: you are testing to see if the `t1` `String` is equal to the `String` `null`. Is that what you want? I think you are trying to see if the `String` `Object` `t1` is `null` in which case you test using regular comparison. (i.e. `t1.toString()!=null`)

Comment: sorry I edited again my code by adding "!" at the start "if" expression...but it couldn't solve the problem again...nothing happens!:(

Comment: why do you want to do that? is that part of your desired logic?

Comment: yes it's exactly what I want , I want to print the number only if it's not equals to 0...

Comment: And what was that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone faced to the same problem as mine , just be sure that there's no problem with this warning :"

```
  09-16 23:57:02.121: W/Editor(27812): GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior
```

just pay attention more ! maybe you have done something funny like me :

```
System.out.print(n1);
System.out.print(m1);
```

I solved my problem by changing `print` with `println` ....
so simple ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String text = editText.getText().toString();

if( text!=null && !text.equalsIgnoreCase("0") ) {
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
  int num2 = num1/100000;
  Log.d(TAG, "Num1 " + num1);
  Log.d(TAG, "Num2 " + num2);
}
```

Comment: TAG is just any string you can set to identify the message - 

    private static final String TAG = "EditTextActivity";